# How to perform max pooling on a 1-dimensional ConvNet (conv1d) in TensowFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm training a convolutional neural network on text (on the character level) and I want to do max-pooling. tf.nn.max_pool expects a rank 4 Tensor, but 1-d convnets are rank 3 in tensorflow ([batch, width, depth]), so when I pass the output of conv1d to the max pool function, this is the error:

```
ValueError: Shape (1, 144, 512) must have rank 4
```

I'm new to tensorflow and deep learning frameworks in general and would like advice on the best practice here, because I can imagine there are multiple workarounds. How can I perform max-pooling in the 1-d case?

Thanks.

Comment: Would it help if you combine [`tf.strided_slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#strided_slice) and [`tf.reduce_max`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduce_max)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick way would be to add an extra singleton dimension i.e. make the shape (1, 1, 144, 512), from there you can reduce it back with tf.squeeze.

I'm curious about other approaches though.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. The Tensorflow documentation explicitly says that the conv1d function is just conv2d under the hood (with the singleton dimension added just as you said). I'm not sure why they added the conv1d function at all if there's no equivalent pooling function.

Comment: It actually took a little while to even add the conv1d function.  Part of the discussion entailed that it was the same as conv2d and if you know you're input is 1D there are better optimizations that one can do. So they might add maxpool1D if it gets popular enough.  Since it is open source you could also do a pull request or add it as an issue for a feature request.

Comment: When you say 'there are better optimizations that one can do' what are you referring to?

Comment: Better optimization means that given knowledge about the input we can more efficiently code up a solution on both gpu and cpu for that case.  That's why cudnn backend is so efficient because there are lots of optimizations done for 2D inputs such as some spatial parallelization.